# Difference between List and Mutable List in Kotlin Generics

Tags: kotlin, generics, mutablelist

I recently study about kotlin Generics, But i found some weird stituation

[IDE image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kCOI.png)

```
interface MyItem

fun <ITEM : MyItem> bindItem(items: List<ITEM>?) {
    val castedItem = items as List<MyItem>?
}

fun <ITEM : MyItem> bindItem2(items: MutableList<ITEM>?) {
    val castedItem = items as MutableList<MyItem>?
}
```

Only In MutableList case compiler warn about unchecked Cast

If anyone knows about this situation, Please tell me about this.

Answer (score 12):

The `List` interface has declaration site *covariance* (`<out T>`). This means it is safe to "upcast" the type because a List only ever outputs items. For example, if you have a `List<Int>`, it is safe to use it as a `List<Number>` because an `Int` can always be safely cast to a `Number`. When you retrieve items from the list, they always satisfy being the type `Int` or the supertype `Number`.

`MutableList` does not have a covariant type. It is *invariant* at the declaration site. This means it is not inherently safe to "upcast" its type. For example, if you cast your `MutableList<Int>` to a `MutableList<Number>`, it is not safe to use the  `MutableList<Number>` reference, because it would let you add a `Float` to the list. When the original reference is used as a `MutableList<Int>` and tries to retrieve a value from it, it will get a ClassCastException for trying to use the `Float` as an `Int`.

In this case, you could safely cast the `MutableList` to a covariant type, like this:

```
val castedItem = items as MutableList<out MyItem>?
```

but a `MutableList` with a covariant type is not really any different than a `List` (except that you can `clear()` it), so it would be better to cast it to a `List<MyItem>` to make the intent clearer.